# R Matrix package: Demean sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Is there a simple way to demean a sparse matrix by columns while considering zero-values as missing (using Matrix package)?

There seem to be two problems I struggle with:

**Finding proper column means**

Empty cells are considered zero rather than missing:

```
M0 <- matrix(rep(1:5,4),nrow = 4)
M0[2,2] <- M0[2,3] <- 0
M <- as(M0, "sparseMatrix")
M
#[1,] 1 5 4 3 2
#[2,] 2 . . 4 3
#[3,] 3 2 1 5 4
#[4,] 4 3 2 1 5
colMeans(M)
#[1] 2.50 2.50 1.75 3.25 3.50
```

Correct result should be:

```
colMeans_correct <- colSums(M) / c(4,3,3,4,4)
colMeans_correct
#[1] 2.500000 3.333333 2.333333 3.250000 3.500000
```

**Subtract column mean**

Subtraction is performed also on the missing cells:

```
sweep(M, 2, colMeans_correct)
#4 x 5 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
#     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]  [,4] [,5]
#[1,] -1.5  1.6666667  1.6666667 -0.25 -1.5
#[2,] -0.5 -3.3333333 -2.3333333  0.75 -0.5
#[3,]  0.5 -1.3333333 -1.3333333  1.75  0.5
#[4,]  1.5 -0.3333333 -0.3333333 -2.25  1.5
```

P.S. hope it is not a problem posting a question composed of two problems. They are connected to the same task and seem to reflect the same problem - distinguish between missing and actual zero values.

Comment: are you sure your final matrix is correct as you seem to be subtracting the column means row wise. This might work `scale(M, center=colSums(M) / diff(M@p), scale=FALSE)`

Comment: @user20650 I corrected the appropriate code to subtract column wise. I put there the `sweep` funtion to show the not working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to divide the `colSums` by the `colSums` of the non-zero logical matrix

```
colSums(M)/colSums(M!=0)
#[1] 2.500000 3.333333 2.333333 3.250000 3.500000
```

Or another option is to replace the 0 with `NA` and get the `colMeans` with `na.rm = TRUE` argument

```
colMeans(M*NA^!M, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2.500000 3.333333 2.333333 3.250000 3.500000
```

---

Or as @user20650 commented

```
colSums(M) / diff(M@p)
#[1] 2.500000 3.333333 2.333333 3.250000 3.500000
```

where the 'p' is a pointer mentioned in the `?sparseMatrix`

> In typical usage, p is missing, i and j are vectors of positive
>   integers and x is a numeric vector. These three vectors, which must
>   have the same length, form the triplet representation of the sparse
>   matrix.
>
> If i or j is missing then p must be a non-decreasing integer vector
>   whose first element is zero. It provides the compressed, or “pointer”
>   representation of the row or column indices, whichever is missing. The
>   expanded form of p, rep(seq_along(dp),dp) where dp <- diff(p), is used
>   as the (1-based) row or column indices.

Comment: I would just add that `sweep(M, 2, colMeans(M*NA^!M, na.rm = TRUE))*NA^!M` does the complete solution, where the `sweep` function is for subtraction.

Comment: and another alt using the sparse matrix structure. `colSums(M) / diff(M@p)`